# Where can the Phoenix be found in Jewish Sources?

Tags: sources-mekorot, animals, myths

What are the earliest sources that refer to the mythological [Phoenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_%28mythology%29) in Judaism?

No need for the name to "phoenix" or "עוף החול" (the modern Hebrew name), but I'm looking for an immortal bird which regenerates itself.

Comment: Why would you expect there to be any such references??

Comment: @DoubleAA Besides the fact that I found references, and am looking for more references, many myths are found in multiple cultures, and since the Rabbis had knowledge of Greek and Roman culture, it would be conceivable that the Phoenix would appear in Judaism.

Comment: So shouldn't you be asking _if_ the phoenix can be found in Jewish sources, and if so, where? Do you also want to ask where Pegasus shows up? And Medusa?

Comment: @DoubleAA I knew that the phoenix shows up, so no need to ask "if". And sure, I would be interested in knowing whether Pegasus or Medusa (or any other Greek / Roman mythological creature) shows up in Rabbinical literature, and if yes, where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Regenerating bird

#### Genesis Rabbah 19:5 – A bird named Chol (עוף אחד ושמו חול)

> האכילה את הבהמה ואת החיה ואת העופות, הכל שמעו לה חוץ מעוף אחד ושמו חול, הה"ד (איוב כט) וכחול ארבה ימים, דבי רבי ינאי אמרי אלף שנה הוא חי, ובסוף אלף שנה אש יוצאה מקנו ושורפתו, ומשתייר בו כביצה וחוזר ומגדל אברים וחי, ר' יודן בר"ש אומר אלף שנים חי ולבסוף אלף שנים גופו כלה וכנפיו מתמרטין ומשתייר בו כביצה וחוזר ומגדל אברים.

Eve fed all the animals from the Tree of Knowledge, but the bird named חול did not eat. The bird lives for 1000 years, then regenerates itself.

### Non-dying bird

#### Bavli Sanhedrin 108b - Urshinah (אורשינה)

> אורשינה, אשכחיניה אבא דגני בספנא דתיבותא. אמר ליה: לא בעית מזוני? אמר ליה: חזיתיך דהות טרידא, אמינא לא אצערך. אמר ליה יהא רעוא דלא תמות, שנאמר (איוב כ"ט) ואמר עם קני אגוע וכחול ארבה ימים.

All the other animals in Noah's Ark were a lot of work to be fed, but אורשינה did not bother Noah, and did not ask for food, so Noah blessed him to not die.

### Entered Paradise alive

#### Otzar HaMidrashim (Eisenstein) pg. 50 – Milchas the bird (מלחס העוף)

> אנשים מבני אדם נכנסו בחיים בגן עדן. (כ"א) אמר לו מי הם? אמר לו חנוך וסרח בת אשר, ובתיה בת פרעה וחירם מלך צור, ואליעזר עבד אברהם ועבד מלך הכושי, ועבדו של רבי יהודה, ויעבץ, ורבי יהושע בן לוי, וכל זרע יונדב וזרעו של מלחס העוף.

Comment: Ther's also the Gemara about a "salamandar" made of ashes.

Comment: @Shalom is סלמנדרה a bird? What is the exact source?